# Java Keystore - cannot load a keystore when varbinary is stored as 0x

Tags: java, sql-server-2016, keystore, varbinary

I have a JKS keystore stored in Microsoft SQL server database. It's stored as varbinary and saved as (for example) `0x539A" - a very long varbinary. The data was loaded using`OPENROWSET(BULK 'location', SINGLE_BLOB) format.

When I do the following on the resultset:

```
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(keys);
    keyStore.load(is, ksPassword.toCharArray());
```

I am getting exception:

```
  java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```

I am not sure how to convert the byte stream such that it appears as something like `[B@sdfsfs' because that's how the byte stream looks like for some other keys. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: I think you should not build the inputStream yourself but rather rely on `getBinaryStream("columnName")` from ResultSet and let the keystore instance deal with it.

Comment: In Java `[B@somehex` is the default display (`toString()`) form of a byte _array_ -- not any stream, and although they contain similar possibly identifical data there is a difference -- but does not indicate anything about the data _in_ the array. Are you saying the first bytes in the stored value _are_ 53 9A? If so that is definitely not a JKS;JKS _always_ has first 4 bytes FE ED FE ED.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using `CONVERT(varbinary(max), '0x0EB882727A', 1)` - it was loaded correctly. The password was the issue.

Comment: You don't need to encrypt a keystore. The keys are already encrypted internally, and it already has its own password.

Comment: @user207421.     it's not about encrypting keys. It's about making sure that the keystore cannot be accessed without password, and resides outside the application control. If necessary (under circumstances), we can redeploy the application and keys with a new password.